# PHP foreach loop and one AJAX call for each of the loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

This question has already been asked here, but I could see any of the answers working for me. 
I have the following code in Laravel 4:

```
<ul class="list-group">
                    @foreach($inboxMsg as $inbox)
                       <li class="list-group-item no-border">

                            <a href="#{{ $inbox->mid }}" id="fragment1g">
                                <span class="no-margin sender center-block"><b>John Doe</b>
                                    <small class="pull-right datestamp"><strong>2:00AM</strong></small>
                                </span>
                                <span>

                                        <strong>{{ $inbox->subject }}</strong> <i class="fa fa-paperclip att"> 3</i>

                                </span>
                            </a>

                        </li>
                    @endforeach

                </ul>
```

As you can see I am passing the ID of each message in the URL with # to prevent page reload and in my AJAX I tried to get the value after # (hash). Here is my AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-group-item a').click(function (event) {

  //Check if the URL has value after hash
  if(window.location.hash) {

 //set the value as a variable, and remove the #
 var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

 //show loader
 $('#loader').fadeIn("slow");

 //Proccess data through Ajax
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ URL::route('post-read') }}",
                data: { mid : hash_value },
                cache: false,
                dataTye: "json",
                success: function(data)
                {

                    $('#loader').fadeOut("slow");

                    alert(data["body"]);
                }
            });;



}
});
  })
    </script>
```

With this code it is working but not correctly. It forces me to click twice before alerting the body of the message, and when I click the second message it first brings the body of the first message, until I click it again before I could see the body of second message. But without this line of Jquery "`$('.list-group-item a').click(function (event){`" the ID is passed in the URL after # (hash) but AJAX call does not work.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Beware, IDs ***must*** be unique on document context. Now regarding your issue, what debugging it shows you? I guess this is due to `if(window.location.hash)` check not working properly on first click, isn't it? If ya, you could delay all this logic or better use onhashchange event instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange

Comment: Of course IDs are unique. onhashchange does not work

Comment: I see that in a foreach loop: `<a href="#{{ $inbox->mid }}" id="fragment1g">`  Now if you have only one instance to iterate, i don't see the purpose of using a loop... Regarding `onhashchange does not work`, it should but the logic must be different of course. You have to take some initiative by debugging it on your side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent page reload after clicking on link

you can directly take `$inbox->mid` using attribute using some data attribute

```
<a data-id="{{ $inbox->mid }}" id="fragment1g">
     <span class="no-margin sender center-block"><b>John Doe</b>
         <small class="pull-right datestamp"><strong>2:00AM</strong>
         </small>
     </span>
     <span>
             <strong>{{ $inbox->subject }}</strong> <i class="fa fa-paperclip att"> 3</i>
          </span>
</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.list-group-item a').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                    var hash_value = $(this).attr("data-id");

                    //show loader
                    $('#loader').fadeIn("slow");

                    //Proccess data through Ajax
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{ URL::route('post-read') }}",
                        data: { mid : hash_value },
                        cache: false,
                        dataTye: "json",
                        success: function(data)
                        {

                            $('#loader').fadeOut("slow");

                            alert(data["body"]);
                        }
                    });

            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Clicking on internal links doesn't reload the page but scroll window to specific element regarding its ID, if any on page

Comment: from question i got that he is using # only to prevent page reload or redirect thats why i have written that

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the window.location.hash. You sholud put the right url in the  element and use event.preventDefault();

PHP:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('post-read', array('mid'=>$inbox->mid)) }}">
```

JS:

```
 event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(this).attr('href'),
                cache: false,
                dataTye: "json",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#loader').fadeOut("slow");
                    alert(data["body"]);
                }
            });;
```